# IOS 7 UITextField resignFirstResponder BAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ios7, resignfirstresponder

Im getting a crash, when using a UItextField, inside my customCell, and when i resignFirstResponder the textfield, but its not visible anymore(the table view scrolled out of window). I still can find the textfield, the pointer continues accessible, it is no null, and the crash only occurs on IOS7, on IOS6 i dont have this problem. Heres some code :

The `textField` is a global variable.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];

    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableCell alloc] init];

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, cell.frame.size.width-60, cell.frame.size.height)];
            textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            textField.tag = indexPath.row;
            textField.delegate = self;
            textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
            [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:15]];
            textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            [textField setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
            textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Senha" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
            [cell.contentView textField];
        }
}
    return cell;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
//    NSLog(@"text field %@",textField);
//    NSLog(@"tfield return: %d",textField.isFirstResponder);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
//    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You have the same textField instance in all UITableViewCells ? It's strange. How to alloc init the textField IVar ?

Comment: i just put one TextField for example but i have :
 if(indexPath.row == 0)
 {
    [textField1 setFrame:CGREctMake(0,0,0,0)];
}
if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
  [textField2 setFrame:CGREctMake(0,0,0,0)];
}

and i init them all in my viewDidLoad @tdelepine

Comment: OK How to alloc init the textField IVar ? and what is the crash message

Comment: I've spent the past day on this exact same issue -- any time a first responder is not visible (for example, scrolled behind the keyboard) and its is resigned, **crash**. My textfield is not a global variable, so the crash isn't related to that. iOS7 only.

Comment: @Answerbot, thanks for the tip, I've successfully reproduced the crash on my app.

Comment: @ZhaoXiang Thanks for the answer below. That was the root cause of my crashing as well. Great to finally have a fix for this.

Comment: darkman: You should mark Zhao's answer as correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've successfully fixed a similar crash bug with the help of Apple. The key is the `reuseIdentifer`.

The quote is from a mail from *Vincent Gable* of *Apple Developer Technical Support*:

> This is a known behavior change that happens in iOS 7 with `UITableView`, when cells are not reused.
>
> The fix here is to make sure that you follow proper cell reuse. If you do not want to re-use `UITableViewCells`, then it is recommended that you simply layout all your views inside a `UIScrollView`.
>
> To make sure cells are re-used, make sure you are passing the same string to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` that you pass to `reuseIdentifier:` when using `alloc/init` to make the cell. This string can not be nil.

So I think you should make sure you've set `TableCell`'s `reuseIdentifer` property with the same value you've passed to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

Comment: +1 This fix works. In my case there was no reuseIdentifier set on the cell in InterfaceBuilder. This likely is not an issue if you are using the more modern approach to cell reuse via registering cells with the tableView, but, if you are still loading nibs manually via loadNibNamed -- as the legacy code I'm working with did -- it will almost certainly bite you at some point.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons, in my case I did not set the `reuseIdentifer` in IB neither. I've never noticed there's such property exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some more research into how UITableViews work and reconsider your design. Storing a UITextField in a global variable and trying to position it like this is not the right approach. Even if you could solve the immediate problem, which is likely that the UITextField has been released along with the UITableViewCell, this design is only going to get you into trouble further down the line.

Instead, consider subclassing UITableViewCell and adding a UITextField property to your subclass.

You probably don't want to be using a different CellIdentifier for every single row either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i've solved.
It's a little bit dirty methot but i think it work.
I store all the cell that cellForRowAtIndexPath create

`if (!cell) 
{
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FormCell_%@",cellID] owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
        [self.allTheCell addObject:cell];
    }`

the app doesn't crash anymore on ios7